# Enable one grid view and disable the other one when they have the same ItemsSource

Tags: xaml, mvvm

I have two Views sitting side by side.They are supplied by the same ItemsSource.

The two views are almost same except the header. What I want is to display one of them by a condition. The condition is the ItemsSource has a property `type`. When `type` is equal to `left` we show the data in the left View. When `type` is equal to `right` we show the data in the right View.

Now they both display data as they have the same ItemsSource. So how to trigger the View?

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,5,5,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                    <telerik:RadGridView

                             ItemsSource="{Binding Result}">
                        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Width="70" Header="User" DataMemberBinding="{Binding User,Mode=TwoWay}" HeaderTextAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"></telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Width="400" Header="Note" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Note,Mode=TwoWay}" HeaderTextAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"></telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
                        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>

                    </telerik:RadGridView>

                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,5,0,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                    <telerik:RadGridView

                             ItemsSource="{Binding Result}">
                        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Width="70" Header="User" DataMemberBinding="{Binding User}" HeaderTextAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"></telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Width="400" Header="Note" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Note}" HeaderTextAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"></telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
                        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>

                    </telerik:RadGridView>

                </StackPanel>
```

Notice: I use MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 0):

How about binding `Result.type` to your grid views' `IsEnabled` property?

Use a converter that compares the type to the converter parameter, and if they match, return true.

Comment: I added the the property `Type` in the ViewModel. But it can not be reached. Not sure why? `  public string Type
        {
            get { return this.type; }
            set
            {
                if (this.type != value)
                {
                    this.type = value;
                    this.OnPropertyChanged("Type");
                }
            }
        }`

Comment: What do you mean be "it can not be reached"? You'll need a converter anyway, because "left" and "right" aren't valid booleans.

Comment: I have the converter. I meant the logic might be wrong. The `result` has not been got, you just bind `result.type` in the first place. It is always null.